# required operation requires elevation

Tags: windows, batch-file

i am trying to use this command in cmd

```
runas /user:Mymachine\kanhaji diskpart
```

but it say

> ```
> RUNAS ERROR : unable to run -diskpart
> 740 : the requested operation requires elevation.
> ```

this is the only user on my system
and it is already an administrator

although going to `C:/windows/System32/diskpart.exe -> right click -> run as administrator`
works fine
but i just want it to do with cmd
i am creating a batch file which will simply hide my disks on all my systems after just running this batch files

```
@echo off
runas /user:Mymachine\Kanhaji diskpart
mypassword
select volume 3
remove letter f
```

i am going to access this batch file through telnet so i have to run it as administrator through command only

Comment: And what is your question? Neither title nor text contains any question. Do you have run in a command prompt window `runas /?` and read the output help? Or do you have read [SS64 - RUNAS](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) or [Microsoft's RunAs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) documentation? A user confirmation for execution of a command which requires administrator privileges is also necessary if the user account is member of local administrator group as long as UAC (user account control) is not disabled completely. Please edit your "question" and add a question.

Comment: runas.exe can't elevate. You could schedule a task that runs the batch script as your admin account with "highest privileges", i.e. elevated. Then run the task manually via `schtasks.exe /run /tn [task name]`.

Comment: @Mofi sir the question is what should I do....
In such situation

Comment: And yes.. I have run `runas /? ` in CMD AND checked the syntax correctly

Comment: [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) may help

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to disable UAC I am not sure which Windows version you are using, but here is a [good start](https://superuser.com/questions/83677/disabling-uac-on-windows-7)

Then running diskpart in a script might be simpler if you using it with the script option. so once UAC has been disabled, you can create a `.cmd` file and a script file.

the script file will contain your actual diskpart commands to perform for instance:
Create a Script file which we will call `myDiskScript.txt` with the content:

```
select disk 4
format quick fs=ntfs label="My Disk"
```

Then create a batch file called `MyDiskBatch.cmd` and insert the commands. i.e

```
diskpart /s f:\myDiskScript.txt
```

Ensure that you point the full path of the `myDiskScript.txt` in the batch file, else it will search for the script in the execution directory.

You can then run the file via scheduler or by manually execution.

The nice thing about this is that you can create a batch file that does some checks and create the `myDiskScript.txt` file based on the result of your initial tests, then execute it, making it fairly dynamic then.

Comment: UAC already disabled... But this solution still didn't served the purpose...
Can I have your email id or any way of contacting to explain thoroughly what I am trying to do and what problems I am facing all the way there

Comment: if you run diskpart from cmdline, does it open diskpart directly or does it ask you with a popup box to allow running diskpart? Secondly, if it MUST run as administrator, it would be easier to run the batchfile as admin and not call diskpart as admin.

Comment: UAC already disabled...
But still its solving the purpose...
Can I have any source to contact you for detailed explanation of the problem...
What I am trying to achieve is much more complicated then just using a script and getting manually to the system...
I can't use ANY KING OF GUI... everything should be done using CMD.(telnet)

Comment: @Kanha_ji, if UAC is disabled (really bad idea), then runas.exe will log on an administrator with an unrestricted access token, so that shouldn't be a problem. However, the secondary logon service calls `CreateProcessAsUser` with the creation flags `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`, which is probably a problem when running this via telnet (ssh?). If UAC is disabled, however, your current logon, which I presume is running CMD, should have admin access already, in which case runas.exe shouldn't be required.

Comment: @eryksun Disabling uac is a vad idea i know... but it is for now only to make this successfull any how... if once successful... i will somehow manage to enable it again and make my code run...
but the problem is even if uac is disabled....
even if i am typing this command in my user account (instead of telnet)
`runas /user:runas /user:DESKTOP-I55R9T2\hp cmd`
it opens a new cmd window with admin priviledges

Comment: but when doing same with `runas /user:desktop-I55R9T2\hp diskpart`
gives
`Attempting to start diskpart as user "DESKTOP-I55R9T2\hp" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - diskpart
740: The requested operation requires elevation.`
why is it so........
why is it not happening with cmd but with DISKPART

Comment: You should not use runas. You are already using the admin account and you should be able to just run diskpart without the runas portion.